# Vlans can't see each other

Tags: vlan

OK so I hope I explain this correctly.

We have the following network setup:

[image]

The issue is that None of the IP phones can ping the computers and vice versa. The reason the phones are on the seperate internet connection is so that if we eat all the bandwidth on the EdgeMAX which only have like 20MBPS it doesn't degrade the phones.

Is this going to be possible to have both networks even see each other? I thought it would have been fairly basic... but I feel like i'm missing some core networking knowledge for this setup... possibly in the ability for the TP links ability to see read routing packets through it's LAn ports but I'm a bit clueless.

Any suggestions as to what's doing wrong and how I could go about repairing it?

Note: switch1 and switch 2 are connected to each other (oopse on the diagram)

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: is there any connection between the two switches or anywhere on the network? If not, then it looks like any such traffic would have to exit to the internet and come back in through the other internet connection.

Comment: Oopse, thanks LYlearn, yes there is a connection through switch1 and 2. Additionally, I've tried putting a cable from one router to the the other on the ethernet ports, that also didn't seem to work.

Comment: Usually the point of separate VLANs is to prevent the devices on one VLAN from interacting with the devices on the other. If you want them all to talk to each other then you wouldn't make two VLANs. If you want them to be on separate IP subnets but still be able to talk to each other then you have to have a router to connect the two subnets.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to enable traffic flow between the two VLANs would to have both the switches connect to the same router (or a layer 3 switch),because traffic between different VLANs needs to be routed.Remember that the ports between the switch and the router should be trunk ports and be enabled for both VLANs.

Comment: Is this even possible if the only interface thats available is switch0 when in the edgemax console. Would I need switch0 and switch1 to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If your routers are connected directly together through separate ports outside of 192.168.1 and 192.168.2, assign a new subnet between them (eg: 172.16.31.1/30 on router A and 172.16.31.2/30 on router B).

Then on the 192.168.1.0/24 router, add a route: 192.168.2.0/24 --> 172.16.31.2. On the 192.168.2.0/24 router, add: 192.168.1.0/24 --> 172.16.31.1.

Answer (score 0):

Question.... why do you have the AP plugged into the router? You're wasting a good FE port. Your AP's should be on the switch plugged into a separate VLAN.

Make sure your ports are trunked.

Try InterVlan Routing, that should be your fix.
[CISCO](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/tech/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/index.html)

Comment: I made this change, thanks! There is a cable set from switch1 to switch2 which is set to trunk.

Comment: So this worked for you?

Comment: Oh Sorry, I meant I plugged the AP into a switch port instead now.

Comment: ahh, okay. I still think you should try Intervlan routing.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to hopefully give it a shot earlier today. Does this mean I have to setup VLANS on the edgemax router AND the switch?

Comment: just the router. InterVLAN routing is to connect separate VLANs together by using a layer 3 device.